# argparse with argument_groups and mututally_exclusive_group

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have the following:

```
def parser():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    people = p.add_argument_group('people_list')
    meg = people.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    meg.add_argument('--config-file')
    g = meg.add_argument_group('people')
    g.add_argument('--name')
    g.add_argument('--age')
    return p

p = parser()

p.parse_args(['--config-file', 'cfg_file', '--name', 'Bob', '--age', '3'])
```

I expect that this will complain due to the `mutually_exclusive` group. Note, this is a snippet of the actual code, I have several `argument_groups` that I need to work with, but in this `argument_group('people_list')`, I want the user to specify either a config file, or any of the other arguments.

So, my user should be able to say

```
prog --config-file cfg_file
```

or

```
prog --name Bob --age 3
```

but not

```
prog --config-file cfg_file --name Bob --age 3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I expect that it will toss an exception due to `devices` being referenced before defined and/or not having an attribute `add_mutually_exclusive_group`...

Comment: @twalberg. Type, fixed. Should have been people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the help:

```
usage: foo [-h] [--config-file CONFIG_FILE] [--name NAME]
                        [--age AGE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

people_list:
  --config-file CONFIG_FILE
```

An argument group like `people` controls how the help lines are shown.  Hence the section titled `people_list`.

A mutually exclusive group controls how the usage is formatted, and checks the cooccurance of the arguments.  Technically it is a subclass of the argument group, but the two kinds of groups don't interact much.

You can nest a mutually exclusive group in an argument group, as you did here.  But you can't nest an argument group in another group (either kind).  Or rather, it will accept such a definition, but it does nothing special.  So `name` and `age` have been added to the parser (as seen in usage), but not to `meg` or `people`.  And if you add a mutually exclusive group to another MXGroup, the effect is to just create a large flat group.

So, with one, minor exception, don't try to nest one group within another.  Their definitions just aren't general enough to do anything useful that way.

If you add `name` and `age` to `meg`, then help will be:

```
usage: foo [-h]
                        [--config-file CONFIG_FILE | --name NAME | --age AGE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

people_list:
  --config-file CONFIG_FILE
  --name NAME
  --age AGE
```

This will object to using `config-file` with either `name` or `age`.  But it will also object to using both `name` and `age`.

There is bug-issue that asks for generalized nested mutually-xxx-groups.  Once implemented it could handle this generalized logic.  But for now, it can't.  Assuming you could set up the tests that you want, what would the ideal usage line look like?  It's relatively easy to setup the tests, but much harder to generate meaningful usage.

For now I'd suggest writing your own `usage`.  Use `argument groups` to group the argument help lines.  Do your own interaction tests after parsing.  You can use `p.error...` to generate error messages.  And if you choose defaults wisely, it isn't hard to test the arguments, e.g.

```
if args.config_file is not None and 
    (args.name is not None or args.age is not None): 
    p.error('...')
```